# Parameters as array copy() not working in resource

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to send array of email values as parameters and trying to deploy 'Action group' using 'Copy' in the resource template .My Action group template is getting deployed without errors but email fields are empty. I was passing two email values as parameters. I'm stuck with this for a day. It would be great if someone throw some lights on where i am going wrong.

Template.json:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "actionGroupName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "newActionGroup",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Unique name (within the Resource Group) for the Action group."
        }
    },
    "actionGroupShortName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "newActionGroup",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Short name (maximum 12 characters) for the Action group."
        }
    },
    "emailReceiverName": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "email receiver service Name."
        }
    },
    "emailReceiverAddress": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "email receiver address."
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "customemailReceiverName": "[array(parameters('emailReceiverName'))]",
    "customemailReceiverAddress": "[parameters('emailReceiverAddress')]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
        "name": "[parameters('actionGroupName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
            "groupShortName": "[parameters('actionGroupShortName')]",
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "counts",
                    "count": "[length(parameters('emailReceiverName'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "emailReceivers": [
                            {
                                "name": "[parameters('emailReceiverName')[copyIndex('counts')]",
                                "emailAddress": "[parameters('emailReceiverAddress')[copyIndex('counts')]]"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
] }
```

Parameter.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "actionGroupName": {
            "value": "actiongroupslb"
        },
        "actionGroupShortName": {
            "value": "agSLB"
        },
        "emailReceiverName": {
            "value": ["siva","siva1"]
        },
        "emailReceiverAddress": {
            "value": ["siva@gmail.com","svaji@gmail.com"]
        }

    }
}
```

[Action group created with missing email values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fct3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's whats working for me:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "name": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].Name]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "ActionGroupCopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('emailReceiverName'))]"
        },
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
            "groupShortName": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].Name]",
            "enabled": true,
            "emailReceivers": [
                {
                    "name": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].EmailName]",
                    "emailAddress": "[variables('actionGroups')[copyIndex()].EmailAddress]"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Here's the variable:

```
    "actionGroups": [
        {
            "Name": "teamname",
            "EmailAddress": "email@domain.com",
            "EmailName": "emailname"
        },
        {
            "Name": "teamname1",
            "EmailAddress": "email1@domain.com",
            "EmailName": "emailname1"
        }
    ],
```

If you need multiple receivers, use the resource property copy function, not resource:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
    "name": "name",
    "location": "Global",
    "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "name",
        "enabled": true,
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "emailReceivers",
                "count": "[length(parameters('emailReceiverName'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[parameters('emailReceiverName')[copyIndex('emailReceivers')]]",
                    "emailAddress": "[parameters('emailReceiverAddress')[copyIndex('emailReceivers')]]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

this is assuming they map 1-to-1

Comment: hi ..thanku for your response. how i can add mutiple emails under single action group? Becoz here wen i try to extend the variable as like below, it is creating two action groups and an email for each group  "actionGroups": [
        {
            "Name": "teamname",
            "EmailAddress": "email@domain.com",
            "EmailName": "emailname"
        },
    {
            "Name": "teamname1",
            "EmailAddress": "email1@domain.com",
            "EmailName": "emailname1"
        }]  Also i want to get the variable values from parameters for reusability

Comment: Sure i deleted.Resource part is working now wen i pass single variable value only "variables": {
          "actionGroups": [
        {
            "EmailName": "user",
            "EmailAddress": "user@hmail.com"
        }
          ]
  }

Comment: Wen i use array parameter value as variable values, its throwing error. How to pass array of parameter values to variable value ? i dnt want to hardcode email values in variables,  and would like pass it via parameters. Error is ""message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed."  "variables": {
          "actionGroups": [
        {
            "EmailName": "[array(parameters('emailReceiverName'))]",
            "EmailAddress": "[array(parameters('emailReceiverAddress'))]"
        }
          ]
  }

Comment: thanks for ur reply again. I already tried ur updated answer thats working..but thats not my requirement. I want to keep my parameters.json file separetely and want to pass that array parameter of email values to variables. I dont want to hardcode in variables section. by this for any change in values,i will touch only parameters.json file for reusuable purpose.

Comment: whatever, move that to parameters, you kidding me or something? it doesnt matter where it is

Comment: sorry. Im new to this ARM templates.Could you pls show me how to pass from the parameters ? It would be really helpful. Im passing like the below now and its not working.   "variables": {
          "actionGroups": [
        {
            "EmailName": "[array(parameters('emailReceiverName'))]",
            "EmailAddress": "[array(parameters('emailReceiverAddress'))]"
        }
          ]
  } ,

Comment: well, it kinda depends on what you are doing, if you just have 2 array, you dont need to create a new object with two array, just reference them directly, check update answer in 5 minutes

Comment: sure waiting for ur answer.

Comment: For sample  only i used two array. i will be adding more to it.

Comment: if you have new requirements accept this answer and create a new question.

Comment: Accepted.i kind of finding how to accept since im new to stackoverflow too..anyways thanku so much for ur response. i will raise a new question.

Comment: thanks, feel free to ping me on this comment section with your new question url

Comment: Thanks  4c74356b41. New question is available in the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556300/azure-arm-passing-array-parameters-values-to-variables